# Flink 1.5-SNAPSHOT web interface doesn't work

Tags: apache-flink

I recently came across a bug in Flink, reported (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8685) and found out that it has been reported and a pull request has been created (https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/5174).

Now I clone 1.5-SNAPSHOT, apply the patch and build Flink. Even though it builds (no matter patch is applied or not), when I run Flink (using *start-cluster.sh*), web dashboard doesn't work and command 
    **tail log/flink-*-jobmanager-*.log** returns "*tail: cannot open 'log/flink-*-jobmanager-*.log' for reading: No such file or directory*"
. I tested with a batch programs and surprisingly it returned results on terminal, but streaming programs and other things still don't work.

Any suggestions on this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Please change flink log level i.e. in conf directory Change INFO to DEBUG. Then check if the port is occupied by other process. Try changing port to 8082.

Comment: Thank you! I checked logs and found out that dashboard runs on port 9065 (I don't really know why). Now I try to debug the rest.

Comment: Flink 1.5-SNAPSHOT is *not* a released version of Flink and changes with every commit on the development branch. Since the behavior of a SNAPSHOT version is not fixed, it doesn't make much sense to ask questions about them on Stack Overflow. Please reach out with questions to the community via [user or dev mailing lists](http://flink.apache.org/community.html#mailing-lists) or report a bugs in [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/FLINK).

Answer (score 0):

1. In case flink dashboard does not start change port in conf file and restart. Default port of flink could be occupied by other process in windows.
2. Also change log level for flink to debug.